# Nullpointer in MultiViewHandler after update to JSF 2.3

Tags: jsf, primefaces

PrimeFaces 12
JSF 2.3.14
EAP 7.4.9

Hello,

I got a Nullpointer after updating an application to JSF 2.3.14 (the main version for JBoss EAP 7.4) from 2.1.19.

> 09:14:54,346 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> 09:14:54,347    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.getRedirectURL(MultiViewHandler.java:390) ~[jsf-impl-2.3.14.SP07-redhat-00001.jar!/:2.3.14.SP07-redhat-00001]

The Primefaces team found a similar problem: [Provide native ClientWindow implementation](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/6030)

[image: Nullpointer Debug]

Do I have to configure anything to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1):

According to that Primefaces post it looks like it was a bug in Mojarra that has been fixed.

See: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/issues/4727

Can you update your Jboss modules folder to use Mojarra 2.3.21 and see if it is fixed.

Comment: I am very restricted in usable versions, so it is 2.3.14 or 2.1.19 (which I am using now). So I assume there is no way to use 2.3.14 with my application because of the missing fix?

Comment: I would guess not if its a bug in Mojarra.  I use Jboss EAP 7.4 and you can easily swap in Mojarra 2.3.21 for it?  Why can't you do that?

Comment: Big company, strict rules what to use...

Comment: Ahhh strict rules is terrible when it comes to bugs and security fixes.  But I understand.